# Release Acquire Semantics to Compute Average

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, memory-barriers

Say there are two functions to update and return the average of some property being measured:

```
void Class::Update( int delta )
{
    m_accumulatedValue += delta;
    ++ m_count;
}

double Class::GetAverage( )
{
    return m_accumulatedValue/(double)m_count;
}
```

Now, suppose they need to be changed to run in a multithreaded environment with a thread pool in which any thread can be requested to execute one of them - that is, the thread executing each one of them can be a different one each time:

```
std::atomic< int > m_accumulatedValue;
std::atomic< int > m_count;

// ...

void Class::Update( int delta )
{
    m_accumulatedValue.fetch_add( delta , std::memory_order_relaxed );
    m_count.fetch_add( 1 , std::memory_order_release );
}

double Class::GetAverage( )
{
    auto count = m_count.load( std::memory_order_acquire );
    auto acc = m_accumulatedValue.load( std::memory_order_relaxed );

    return acc/(double)count;
}
```

I'm trying to understand the acquire and release memory orderings.

Suppose there's no concurrent calls on the same object for `Update()`, but may be concurrent calls on the same object for `Update()`  and `GetAverage()`.

For what I've read, the acquire load of `m_count` in `GetAverage()` forbids the reordering of the load of `m_accumulatedValue` before it and *at the same time* guarantees that any change to `m_accumulatedValue` performed by `Update()` is visible by the thread calling `GetAverage()` once the change to `m_count` is also seen, for the store performed on `m_cout` by `Update()` has a release ordering.

Is what I've just said right?

Does `GetAverage()` (with the said guarantee of non-concurrency of the calls to `Update()`) always return the right answer? Or there can be a way of it returning the calculated average with some of the values "more updated" than the other?

Does `m_accumulatedValue` need to be atomic at all?

Comment: `memory_order_relaxed` doesn't forbid the other thread from seeing the new value, it just doesn't require it. So there could still be a race condition.

Comment: Aside from the memory order semantics, this code is broken. One possible execution order is that one thread adds to `m_accumulatedValue`, then another thread reads `m_accumulatedValue` **and** `m_count`, then the first thread updates `m_count`. The average calculated by the second thread will be wrong.

Comment: No. No. Maybe. No. Why not use mutual exclusion?

Comment: I would avoid using `memory_order_relaxed` as even the experts can't figure out the exact semantics. Instead prefer acquire/release if you must use not strict semantics.

Comment: @PeteBecker, in such a case the miscalculated average would be higher than the correct value, right? Is it safe to say that this is always the case? I mean, as `m_count` is being dealt with by release-acquire, the `GetAverage()` will always see at least those increments to `m_accumulatedValue` that lead to the increment of `m_count` but maybe some more.

Comment: @jotik, I know I should be using a mutex. This is kind of an exercise. Every time I see a place when I think I could use some non trivial atomics, it turns out I'm wrong =/

Comment: @Tarc: The miscalculated average will be larger in magnitude than one of the correct results, but not necessarily greater.

Comment: @BenVoigt, ok. You mean negatives values, right? I was assuming positive integers.

Comment: By the way, I turned this comment on the miscalculated average on a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42008967/1254880

Answer (score 0):

Your description of how acquire/release semantics work is correct;
they are used to create an inter-thread *happens-before* relationship between memory operations before the store/release and after the load/acquire...
This is based on a run-time relationship and is *only* defined if the atomic load/acquire sees the value that was set by the store/release.

The first problem with your code is that it fails to meet this run-time requirement.
The value of `m_count` is not checked and therefore the ordering guarantees do not apply; you could therefore as well have used `memory_order_relaxed` on all operations.

But that alone does not solve the problem; when you read `m_accumulatedValue`, its value may have changed again by another call to `Update()` (`m_accumulatedValue` therefore has to be atomic).
Futhermore, as pointed out in the comments section, since there is no atomicity between the atomic operations, `GetAverage()` may be called before `Update()` is finished and return an incorrect value.

What you need is strict ordering between `Update()` and `GetAverage()` and the best way to do that is with a `std::mutex`. The atomic variables can then be regular integers (if not used elsewhere).